# Winforms UserControl has unwanted border at the bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, designer

i have created a userControl with no borders and no padding. I added a button to it with Dock.Fill and also no padding. I assumed the button would be as big as the userControl. And that seems to be right in the designer. But as soon as i start the application the button is actually smaller. The userControl clips the bottom somehow.

Why is that? Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: DesignView]

[image: ProgramView]

Kind regards

Comment: What do we see ??

Comment: *"the button is actually smaller"* - the theme is applied and the size of text input was increased, resizing `TextBox`. You need to create layout which support themes. Try using `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: @TaW We see that the Button has the same height as the TextBox in Snapshot1 (Designer) But is smaller in Snapshot2 (Runtime)

Comment: @Sinatr I added a TableLayoutPanel with 1 row/column but the result is still the same

Comment: I also tried setting the AutoScaleMode of the userControl to "None" Didn't help either

Comment: I strongly suspect it's layout problem, it would be easier to help after seeing it. You keep saing "user control", perhaps you just need to move layout logic in or out.

Comment: It's quite *clear*, looking at these images, that your app is not DpiAware. It should be. Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), enhance with [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) -- You should decide whether your app scales on Font or Dpi, with some (a lot :) of testing, you can do both. Controls may scale differently in the same context: find a Layout that fits (here, probably vertical-center)

Comment: Note that DpiAwareness support in WinForms is (still) partial/incomplete. As mentioned, some UI elements may *react* differently when scaled. As also noted in comments, use a Container for your Controls - a TableLayoutPanel could do. Test different alignments, use the `Anchors` and/or `Dock` features until you find the correct Layout. -- I suggest you try first to scale on Dpi (`AutoScaleMode = Dpi`, it's more *consistent*). when you have the hang of it, test mixed scaling (Font and Dpi), using appropriate containers and consider the inheritance of these properties.

Comment: Well it's definitely the high resolution monitor. I restarted the studio on my second monitor which is only FullHD and now it appears to be sized correctly.

Thanks for the help